# @ManyToMany errors unsaved transient instance or duplicate entry

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many

I have 2 entities in a @ManyToMany relationship: Networks and SiteCodes.

Networks:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "network_id")
public int getNetworkId() {
    return this.networkId;
}

public void setNetworkId(int networkId) {
    this.networkId = networkId;
}

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "site_code_map", 
joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "network_id") },  
inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "site_code_id") })
public Set<SiteCodes> getSiteCodes() {
    return siteCodes;
}

public void setSiteCodes(Set<SiteCodes> siteCodes) {
    this.siteCodes = siteCodes;
}
```

SiteCodes:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "site_code_id")
public Integer getSiteCodeId() {
    return this.siteCodeId;
}

public void setSiteCodeId(Integer siteCodeId) {
    this.siteCodeId = siteCodeId;
}

@Column(name = "site_code", nullable = false)
@NotNull
@NaturalId
public String getSiteCode() {
    return siteCode;
}

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="siteCodes",cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
public Set<Networks> getNetworks() {
    return networks;
}

public void setNetworks(Set<Networks> networks) {
    this.networks = networks;
}
```

And my Main class:

```
session.beginTransaction();

Networks nw1 = new Networks(345);
Networks nw2 = new Networks(789);

SiteCodes sc1 = new SiteCodes("0123");
SiteCodes sc2 = new SiteCodes("0001");
SiteCodes sc3 = new SiteCodes("0ABC");

// The real code would do this inside a loop, ie create a new network, figure out 
// the site codes and assign them.
session.beginTransaction();
Networks nw1 = new Networks(345);
nw1.getSiteCodes().add(sc1);
nw1.getSiteCodes().add(sc2);
session.merge(nw1);
session.getTransaction().commit();

session.beginTransaction();
Networks nw2 = new Networks(789);
nw2.getSiteCodes().add(sc3);
nw2.getSiteCodes().add(sc2);
session.merge(nw2);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

The result is a duplicate entry error:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '0001' for key 'site_code'
```

I've played around with CascadeType and anything else I can think of.  I've scoured the existing questions on this topic but haven't found a way to fix this yet.  Occasionally in the variations I've tried I have received "object references an unsaved transient instance" error instead.

Answer (score 0):

Very basic!  (hopefully this will help other neophytes learn something fundamental)

The problem is that the 2nd time the site code is used, it is simply a SiteCode object the contains duplicate information.  Hibernate tries to insert is as a new record.

For the update to occur correctly that SiteCode needs to be a managed object, ie it needs to have been loaded from the database.

Replace the 2nd transaction with this and the problem goes away:

```
session.beginTransaction();
SiteCodes sc4 = (SiteCodes) session.bySimpleNaturalId(SiteCodes.class).load(sc2.getSiteCode());
Networks nw2 = new Networks(789);
nw2.getSiteCodes().add(sc3);
nw2.getSiteCodes().add(sc4); // Same as sc2
session.merge(nw2);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Thanks to my co-worker who pointed this out.